# Check for multiple files

Tags: sql, triggers, business-intelligence, ssis

Okay, I'll try to explain as good as I can... Quite a particular case.

Tools: SSIS 2008

We have a control flow that now needs to be **triggered** by an event: the presence of one or multiple files. (1,2 or 3)

The variables used:

```
BO_FileLocation_1
BO_FileLocation_2
BO_FileLocation_3
BO_FileName_1
BO_FileName_2
BO_FileName_3
```

There can be one, two or three files: defined in above variables. When they are filled in,
they should be processed. When they are empty, this means there's just one file file, the process should ignore them and jump to the next (file watcher?) task.
For example:

```
BO_FileLocation_1= "C:\"
BO_FileLocation_2 NULL
BO_FileLocation_3 NULL
BO_FileName_1= "test.csv"
BO_FileName_2 NULL
BO_FileName_3 NULL
```

The report only needs one file.

I'd need a generic concept that checks the presence of these files, it could be more generic than my SSIS knowledge can handle right now. For example handy, when there's a 4th file in the future. I was also thinking to work with a single script to handle all the logic.

Thanks in advance

A possibly irrelevant image:
[image]

Comment: Would this be an accurate summary: what's a generic approach to ensuring N files exist prior to running a data flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to trigger the `Copy Source File to handle` if one or more of the files is present, just use the OR Constraint in your flow. The following image shows you how:

First connect all to the destination:
[image: Original layout]

Then click one of the green arrows. This will make its properties window pop up. Select the `Logical OR`instead of the `Logical AND`:
[image: precedence constraint properties]

If everything went well, you should now see the connections as dashed lines:

[image: final look]

Comment: I don't believe this is a viable solution as outlined above.  If the business need is to "Do something" after importing all available files, this would violate the business rule.  It would simply start the "Do something" command as soon as at least one file was imported.  Furthermore, it will run the "Do something" if the task completes and there is no file.

Comment: From what i read in the question, it only needs to correctly import one of the files. I might have misunderstood it though.

Comment: Thanks Guys I appreciate your solutions: I think I'll go with the precendence contraint task. (should have thought about that! but hey, exploring the tasks / possibilities of SSIS)

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible solutions:

1. Create a sequence container and include all the file imports in the sequence container.  Add int variables for RowCountFile1, RowCountFile2, and RowCountFile3 and set the value to 0 (this is the default value when you create an int variable).  Add a RowCount transformation to each of the data flows.  Create a precedence constraint from the sequence container to the "Do something" task.  Set the precedence constraint to success and expression.  Set the expression value to @RowCountFile1 > 0 || @RowCountFile2 > 0 || @RowCountFile3 > 0.  The advantage of this approach is that you can take an action as soon as the files are detected, you import all available files, and you only take an action after all the files have been imported.  You could then schedule running this SSIS package as a SQL Server Agent job step and run it as frequently as you want.
2. A variant on solution 1 is to use for each file enumerator containers inside the sequence container.  This would be useful if you don't know the exact name of the file and you expect to import more than one under some circumstances.  For instance, if you get a file every few minutes with a timestamp in its file name and your process doesn't run for some reason, then you may have to process multiple files to get caught up and then take an action once it has been done.
3. You could use the file watcher task as you outlined in your question.  The only problem I have with the file watcher task is that the package has to be in a constantly running state.  This makes it hard to troubleshoot problems and performance.  It also can introduce other problems since I remember having some problems with the file watcher task years ago when it first came out.  It may well be a totally stable task now, but I prefer other methods over the task after having been burned previously.  If you really want the package to run continously instead of having it be called by a job, then you could always use a script task to check for file, sleep thread if not found, check again, etc.  I'm sure that's what the file watcher task does, but I would trust my own C# over the task.  Power to anyone who has had better experiences than me with File Watcher...
4. Use PowerShell.  If you just want to take an action if a file appears and you aren't importing the data, then a PowerShell script could do this just as well as a SSIS package.  The drawback is that you have to learn some basic PowerShell, it may be hard to maintain in the future since PowerShell is probably not your bread and butter core language, and you may have to rewrite the code again to a SSIS package if you want to import the data.  You would probably call the PowerShell script from a SQL Server Agent job step, so scheduling can be handled pretty easily.

There are more options than what I listed, so let me know if you still want more suggestions.

Comment: Thanks Guys I appreciate your solutions: I think I'll go with the precendence contraint task. (should have thought about that! but hey, exploring the tasks / possibilities of SSIS)